# Related product not adding to cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, related-products

I made a custom module for adding products to cart with help of ajax. Here I'm adding related products too. But the problem is that related products are not adding to cart. In my controller

```
public function execute()
{

    $productId = $this->getRequest()->get('id');
    $currentProduct = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
    $this->registry->register('product', $currentProduct);
    $resultRedirect = $this->_pageFactory->create();

    $message['html']= $resultRedirect->getLayout()
        ->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related")
        ->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::product/list/items.phtml")
        ->setData('type', 'related')
        ->toHtml();

       return $this->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->jsonData->jsonEncode($message)
        );

}
```

I debugged in `related-products.js` and found that when I clicked on checkbox it is getting attached to function but not adding to cart.

[image]

Comment: Check in var/log/exception.log file What error is coming there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the product to the cart, something like the below. Please don't use the object manager and instead instantiate the `Cart` class via the constructor (it's below for demonstration purposes only).

```
/** @var $cart \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart */
$cart = \Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->create(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart::class);
$requestInfo = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['qty' => 1]);
$cart->addProduct($currentProduct, $requestInfo);
$cart->save();
```

You'll probably also need to trigger an update of the mini cart, otherwise it'll probably only appear after a page refresh.

Also, I'd consider adding a fromkey check to ensure the request came from onsite.